# Realtek wireless adapter not detected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, suspend, realtek

I have a tablet come PC laptop i have installed Ubuntu 16.10 , i experience a strange behavior when i boot the system Wireless adapter is not detected but i suspend the system a few times it detects the wireless card and connect and work fine but sometime  also just got disconnected while working

I tried many solutions none seems to work for me 
here is the output of iwconfig command when it is connected

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx7cc709cb1699  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"DIY"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 2C:E4:12:4E:A3:53   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:34   Missed beacon:0
```

when it does not works

```
wlx7cc709cb1699  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

kindly guide what is goging wrong i also compiled two driver

```
rtl8723au
rtl8723bu
```

but problem remain the same

kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem by running the following commands in the following order

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8xxxu
sudo modprobe 8723bu
sudo modprobe -r 8723bu
sudo modprobe 8723bu
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

- The first command removes the default module loaded for the Network Card by the kernel.
- The second command loaded the right driver "8723bu" which we compiled earlier.

The rest of the command sequence is necessary to make the network manager detect the network card successfully, Once loaded it will work fine and never disconnect while working, however you have to repeat this process on every system boot.